# How to set a date in DatePicker

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I want `DatePicker` shows a specific date when opened, unfortunately seems I can set only the date limits with `setMinDate` and `setMaxDate`.

Is there a way to set a date without block the selection with date limits?

Comment: what's a `DatePiker` and why does it pike dates...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DatePicker date = new DatePicker(context);  
date.init(year, month, day, null);
```

where year, month and day are ints. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#init%28int,%20int,%20int,%20android.widget.DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener%29) is an explanation about `init`

Comment: I've updated my answer. The getDate was my little personal code which I didn't remove lol